# how can i reliably wait for XHR requests after loading a page in a Cypress test?

Tags: cypress

in my app, when i visit a page it makes some network requests to fetch data and display it on the page. after that you click buttons and fill in fields to filter that data.

i have a cypress test that will basically visit the page, apply some filters, and make sure the stuff in the dom looks right:

```
it(`filters the data by 'price'`, () => {
  cy.server()
  cy.route('POST', 'http://my-api.biz/api').as('apiRequest')

  cy.visit('/')

  // initial page load loads the min and max price bounds for the UI,
  // as well as the data to initially populate the page. they happen
  // to hit the same URL with different POST params
  cy.wait(['@apiRequest', '@apiRequest'])

  cy.get('#price-filter-min').type('1000')
  cy.get('#price-filter-max').type('1400')

  // wait for data to get refreshed
  cy.wait('@apiRequest')

  cy
    .get('[data-test-column="price"]')
    .each($el => {
      const value = parseFloat($el.text())
      expect(value).to.be.gte(1000)
      expect(value).to.be.lte(1400)
    })
})
```

however sometimes cypress seems to load the page, do the XHR requests **before** waiting, then sporadically it'll fail on:

> CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 30000ms for the 2nd response to the route: 'apiRequest'. No response ever occurred.

because it's waiting for a request that has already happened.

is there a better way to write this test? is there a way to visit a page and wait for XHR requests that avoids this race condition?

**UPDATE**

i've tried to re-create this in an isolated test case, but it all seems to be working right, so there's probably some operator error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So most of the answers are deprecated now. As of Cypress@6.4.0, you should use `intercept()`.

Here's how I did mine:

```js
cy.intercept({
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://my-api.biz/api/**",
    }).as("dataGetFirst");
cy.wait("@dataGetFirst");
```

And that's it. You could do more and do an assertion chain on the wait but it's already an assertion by itself.

Comment: Painfully buggy. I found at least two bugs, labeled as "resolved", in the Cypress bug tracker. It still only works in about 1 of 20 times. The other 19 times the wait just times out.

Answer (score 53):

You can do something like this:

```javascript
// Give an alias to request
cy.intercept({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/odata/locations/**',
}).as('dataGetFirst');

// Visit site
cy.visit('admin/locations');

// Wait for response.status to be 200
cy.wait('@dataGetFirst').its('response.statusCode').should('equal', 200)

// Continue
```

Comment: I had to replace: `cy.wait('@dataGetFirst').its('status').should('be', 200);` with `cy.wait('@cartIsUpdating').its('status').should('equal', 200);`

Comment: Similar to Zeth I had to do `cy.wait('@getSomething').its('response.statusCode').should('equal', 200)`. Maybe it's because `cy.server` is now replaced with `cy.intercept`? The answer should be updated to the current Cypress version.

Comment: this doesn't guarantee that the data is going to be painted on the UI so be careful with that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `cy.visit('/')`, I assume you have a baseUrl set in your configuration. The URL parameter in `cy.route()` does baseUrl + the string you pass as a parameter behind the scenes.

So the URL it's sending the POST request to is `http://my-api.biz/apihttp://my-api.biz/api` or something like that.

Try changing your route command to:

`cy.route('POST', '/api/foobar').as('apiRequest')`

**Additional Documentation and Examples:** *[Network Requests, Fixtures](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Fixtures)*

Comment: If you test this, you actually find it is incorrect. baseUrl is not involved in the matching of the route.

Comment: Yes it is. Look at the examples here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html

It's also how I implement it successfully in all of my tests.

Comment: Where does it refer to baseUrl on that page?

Comment: Look at the examples. Are they using 'http://website.com/route' or are they using '/route'?

Comment: From what you are saying, it seems there's a misunderstand of what `cy.route()` does - it matches the route, it does not call it.

Comment: If you `cy.wait(..).then(xhr => console.log(...))` you will not see the mish-mash url you suggested.

Comment: If you are looking at the `matchBase` option, this is what it means [minimatch#matchbase](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch#matchbase)